# Как читать json по ссылке?

Tags: javascript, html, json

Почему я не могу прочитать json по ссылке?
Если читать открытым массивом, то без проблем читается.

Мой пример:

```js
/* Так не читается */
var jsonlink = 'http://localhost/test/products.json'
const data = jsonlink;


/* Так читается выполняет функцию */
  var data = {
    "status": "ok",
    "count": 5,
    "products": [{
        "id": 203848165,
        "url": "/product/bottega-veneta",
        "title": "Bottega Veneta",
        "short_description": "мини-клатч The Pouch"
      },
      {
        "id": 203942281,
        "url": "/product/bugatti-tovarro",
        "title": "Bugatti Tovarro",
        "short_description": "моя личное название производителя"
      },
      {
        "id": 203848009,
        "url": "/product/fabio-bruno",
        "title": "Fabio Bruno",
        "short_description": "коньячная сумка-седло"
      },
      {
        "id": 203848011,
        "url": "/product/alex-santo",
        "title": "Alex Santo",
        "short_description": "коньячная alex-santo"
      },
      {
        "id": 203848022,
        "url": "/product/armani-tarasso",
        "title": "Armani Tarasso",
        "short_description": "лучшая armani-tarasso"
      },
    ]
  }
```

Полный функционал можно посмотреть здесь
https://jsfiddle.net/j2FunOnly/r20Lh5u3/

Спасибо

Comment: а в браузере что нибудь возращается когда вводите путь http://localhost/test/products.json? То делайте обычный запрос на свой сервер

Comment: А где в примере идет обращение к серверу?

Comment: Используйте `AJAX`, по-другому никак

Comment: не знаю как это сделать ?

Answer (score 0):

Можете как показано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706046/how-to-read-an-external-local-json-file-in-javascript/19706080)

вот из странички [jQuery.getJSON()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
  });
 
  $( "<ul/>", {
    "class": "my-new-list",
    html: items.join( "" )
  }).appendTo( "body" );
});
```